# Multiple Points find meetup Points

Tags: sql, postgis

I have stored lots of points with latitude & longitude in my database.

Now I would like to find a "meeting point" (= smallest sum of all the distances from every point in the database to point x -> "meeting point")

Is there some sort of algorithm to solve this problem or am I best with approximating the result?

Comment: Hm, not sure, but isn't this meeting point something like the center point of the convex hull over all points in the DB?

Comment: On a plan, this is the average of the x- and y- coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The meeting point (as described in the question) is just the average of the points in some sense. How complex the answer is depends on how far apart your points are. If they're all relatively close (say, within a city) then you can actually just average the latitude and longitude values since the earth is locally quite close to flat.

If they're further apart, then you'll want to convert out of lat/long into cartesian coordinates first, then average the points, then convert back to lat/long.

If they're far enough apart that you have to worry about locations "rolling over" and having multiple paths to the center (say, some points go around the world east or west depending on where the center precisely is) then you may want to do one iteration to get a "rough point", re-center your coordinates around that rough point, then re-calculate to get an exact point.

Comment: No problem, if you provide more information on how the points are dispersed and your schema we can try to provide something more specific, but I hope this at least helps to get you started.